# How to express xRy & yR-z & x!=z?

Tags: owl, protege

I'm doing an ontology about genealogy and I found out that I can use chain property to easily express some properties. So I have the two properties *hasChild* and *hasParent* (one is the opposite of the other).

I want to create a relation *hasSibling* that says:

> forall x, y, z: hasSibling(x, z) = hasParent(x, y) and hasChild(y, z)

So I create the property *hasSibling* and defined it using chain property as:

> hasParent o hasChild -> hasSibling

The problem is that a person is its own sibling. And I know it's normal because I never said that x != z. So my question is: how can I express this using Protégé?

Please do not hesitate to correct my question if necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to find the count of the children of y? If so, then the number of children of the parent > 1 would be the thing to check in hasSibling.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. I try to use the irreflexive characteristic, but the reasoner (HermiT) don't want to accept characteristics on property definer by chain.

Comment: Can you get the children of a parent?

Comment: That is correct, you can't make the property irreflexive and then use it as super property in a property chain axiom. This is necessary to ensure decidability of OWL 2 DL reasoning. Using an SWRL rule is an alternative: `hasChild(?y,?z), hasChild(?y,?x), DifferentFrom(?x,?z) -> hasSibling(?x,?z)`

Comment: Ok, so I used ``hasChild(?y, ?z) ^ hasChild(?y, ?x) ^ differentFrom(?x, ?z) -> hasSibling(?x, ?z)``. I had a little problem because I didn't define the people as being different, so I think the _DifferentFrom_ was not true. But once I changed this, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yeah, due to no UNA in OWL, you have to make individuals pairwise distinct explicitly via axioms. Forgot to say this but glad you already figured it out :D